# place a comma in front of the found REGEX (4 digits and a comma) in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm working in Java and trying to set a comma in front of a date with 4 digits. Example:

Normal string:

> 'El Burro' Van Rankin,Jorge,5 June 1964,NULL

I want the following output (placing a comma in front of 1964):

> 'El Burro' Van Rankin,Jorge,5 June ,1964,NULL

This is the regex I've made:
`line = line.replaceAll("(\\d{4},)", ",\1");` *// if it finds a 4 digit number followed by a comma replace it with a comma and then the group 1 (1964,)*

If I run this I get the following output:

> 'El Burro' Van Rankin,Jorge,5 June ,NULL

It removes the whole year 1964. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define the backreference with `$`: `line.replaceAll("(\\d{4},)", ",$1")`. Maybe `replaceAll("\\b\\d{4},", ",$0")` will be even cleaner.

Comment: thanks, that works fine ;d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace string has a `\1` in it, whereas it should be `$1`. Thats the only problem that I can see.

```
line.replaceAll("(\\d{4},)", ",$1")
```

or maybe even this if you want something neater:

```
replaceAll("\\b\\d{4},", ",$0")
```